# Mercurial shelve extension - how can you view the diff of a shelf?

Tags: mercurial, shelve

I see no documentation on how to do this in [the docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShelveExtension).

Answer (score 59):

`hg shelve -l -p [name of shelf]`.

To get the shelves list one could use `hg shelve -l`.

Comment: This works, but the `-l` isn't needed (at least as of Mercurial 6.5).

Answer (score 7):

Two ways:

1. `hg unshelve --inspect --name [name-of-shelf]`
2. `cat .hg/shelves/[name-of-shelf]`

Comment: At least as of the hg version I'm running (2.8.2), neither of these quite work. There's no `--inspect` option on unshelve. The second will work (and be a bit more flexible) as:  `cat \`hg root\`/shelved/NAME.patch`

Answer (score 4):

Try, `hg shelve --patch name` — worked for me in Mercurial v 3.6.3